# Create Android Wifi Chat application

Tags: java, android, wifi, project, chat

I am totally new to android as well as java for android programming.
I have to create an android app which uses wifi to chat with the devices available in the available wifi area.
I wouls like to know how can i implement this?
What are the requirements to create such app?
If it is already created, i would like to download one for the reference purpose.
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google already released an example doing just this using the wifi discovery service API that was added into Android 4.  You can find it [here.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/discovery)